# Is there a way to automate data toggle on Galaxy S7 (Edge)

Tags: battery-life, automation, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I recently bought a Galaxy S7 Edge. I've meticulously gone through settings for notifications, sync, permissions to eliminate things doing stuff in the background as much as I can find, but none of this makes much difference to battery life. The only decent difference to battery life is made by manually switching data off before locking (and on, if I want to do something that requires data, after unlocking)

If I leave data on all the time I get about 30 hours.

If I habitually turn data off when I'm not using the phone I get about 3 days (even with regular turning the phone on and data on to check emails, do internet stuff)

(*Note:* I owned an iphone 6 plus before this, and that lasted days with similar use,  without turning data off)

I've tried JuiceDefender  (Which I already own for an older phone) and Tasker. Neither seem to be capable of turning the data on/off. It seems Samsung's version of Android makes that ability unavailable to third party apps.

Does anyone know of a way around this, other than rooting the phone/OS?

Comment: I can't really help. All I can add is I bought Juice Defender only to realize it constantly crashes and throws errors. So yeah it does not seem to work on default Samsung ROM/Android. I will try another saver app and try to see if it works with these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30 hours probably isn't too bad, especially if you use your phone a lot.

If you're in an area where reception is poor, this will also have a negative effect on battery.

There are apps on the Play Store ('Tasker' is one, 'Macrodroid' is another) that you can use to setup macros which perform certain tasks/functions based on the conditions you provide.

There may be a condition within one of those apps that state when the phone is locked, disable data. When unlock, enable it.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried tasker though and it doesn't seem to be authorised to turn data on/off, even if I manually give it as many permissions as possible.  I'll try the other one you mention.